# Jooq foreign key relation

Tags: java, spring-boot, jooq, spring-boot-jooq

How does work foreign key relations in JOOQ? Let me clarify a bit:

1. Main table - A
2. Foreign table - B

In code you can call a method to access main table using foreign table B.a().

Let's say I am calling

> dsl.select(B.a().ID).from(B).fetchInto(String.class);

Does it use left join inside the box of JOOQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Implicit path joins](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/implicit-join/) default to using a `LEFT JOIN` if your foreign key is nullable, and `INNER JOIN` if your foreign key is non-nullable.

> The default type of join that is generated is:
>
> `INNER JOIN` for to-one path segments with non-nullable parent
> `LEFT JOIN` for to-one path segments with nullable parent

But you can override this behaviour if you always prefer a `LEFT JOIN`, for example:

```java
Settings settings = new Settings()
    .withRenderImplicitJoinType(RenderImplicitJoinType.LEFT_JOIN);
```